# Account for Line Returns in Regex for Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

Just learned basics of regex today, and, with some effort, managed to knock together something that ALMOST works.

I've got documents from a book where I need to find articles (a, an, the) within bullets, as opposed to prose.

**Sample of a bullet:**

· Lorem ipsum lorem (XXX) Lorem · Lorem **the** ipsum · Lorem ipsum, lorem, and

**Sample of prose:** 
(Right) **The** lorem wrote **the** ipsum. Lorem ipsum verb ipsum.

So far this does the trick more or less:

```
$regexArticles = "^·\ [\w ,:;()+-=&·]*\b( the | a | an |The |An )\b.*$"
$articlecount = Select-String -Path $textfile -Pattern $regexArticles -AllMatches
"Article Count: " + $articlecount.Matches.Count
```

To make that a little more readable, I'll explain my thinking: 
If the line begins with a bullet and what follows is any number of words and the characters: ", : ( ) + - = & . ;", grab it if there's also articles.

Problem, this doesn't grab the line for the following case:

· Lorem ipsum lorem (XXX) Lorem · Lorem **the** ipsum · Lorem ipsum, lorem, and

lorem lorem **the** lorem lorem

How do I retain this sort of logic when the string I want to grab contains line breaks such as this?

If there's an easier way, perhaps just excluding all sentences that contain a period, that would be great (the only problem with that is sometimes those bullets will incorrectly contain periods).

*EDIT*

Just realized what "almost" worked in my sublime text editor didn't really work at all in Powershell. For whatever reason, even though this returns matches in regex with sublime text, it does NOT for Powershell.

Now I know why. Whereas sublime can handle the bullet character, the shell couldn't, so it was omitted and I didn't notice. Now I just need to know the proper way to grab the bullet unicode and pass it in the same way.

Comment: Perhaps, you may leverage `Get-Content $textfile -Raw` to read the file in with newlines, and then use something like `(?i)^· [\w ,:;()+=&·-]*\b(the|an?)\b.*(?:(?:\r?\n){2}.*)?$`

Comment: This sounds like it would work and certainly does what I need it to in terms of grabbing the right lines, but for some reason,  it returns a count of zero. I think this is a gap in my understanding of how regex is handled in Powershell versus a text editor like Sublime.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think I figured out my problem is a unicode handling one. In lieu of the bullet character there, do you know how to pass the unicode for a bullet like that? I'm looking it up but struggling a bit. Will let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: Middle dot you have at the start of the pattern belongs to `\p{Po}` class. What do you mean by "bullet unicode"? What are the actual requirements for the pattern? `\ud183` is `톃 ‎D183 [Hangul Syllables]` - do you really want that?

Comment: When I said d, I actually meant ASCII (decimal value). This grabs the ascii char code if I'm not mistaken. `[byte][char]'·'`, and returns `183`. I believe when the file I'm reading is saved out after I run pdftotext (xpdf), it's saving as unicode. When I open the text file it's an unreadable character. I'm thinking if I change the encoding that will be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a somewhat hackish fix, because I could not figure out how to detect the middle dot character (u00B7) | (d183), I was able to workaround it by excluding what I did NOT want to find.

```
"^[^\d^(^\s] *\b( the | a | an |The |An )\b.*$"
```

I didn't want any lines that began with a number, and I did not want lines that began with an open parenthesis. For now, this works. Unfortunately, I'm going to have to resolve this issue for other regex searches for my application to be useful.

In answer to my original questions, I had an epiphany that I could just add the optional \n? to account for potential line breaks! Final expression looks like this:

```
^[^\w\d\s(].*\n?\r*?.*\b( the | a | an |The |An )\b.*$
```

Comment: `[^(\d|\()]*` = `[\d()|]` - matches any char other than digit, `(`, `)` and `|`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Is this just an abbreviated equivalent? The vertical bar I was using as an "or" and the close parenthesis there I was using as an end to the group there, so I don't necessarily care about the close parenthesis and the vertical bar as characters as those will never be the start to a line in the documents.

Comment: `[...]` is a character claas where you define *characters*, not groups. A `(`, and `|` are literal chars in there.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So would [\d(] and (\d | \() be roughly equivalent?

Comment: `[\d(]` = `(?:\\(|\d)`